# Dialogflow bot not invoking on Google assistant/ simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant

I have dialogflow agent which when tried to invoke on Google assistant/simulator it say "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."
In the debug section it says "Please turn on Voice & Audio Activity, Web & App Activity (including Chrome browsing history), and Device Information permissions for your Google Account at [https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols"](https://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrols%22). This permission is already enabled in my account.
This same bot is working fine on other IDs which have same roles/permissions which my ID has.
Please help me resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Earlier this enabling and disabling took 24 hours. I am not sure about now, this seem the sync issue , wait for 24hr.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Hi Abhinav, it's been 48+ hrs but still facing the same issue. Please let me know if you know any way to tackle this issue. Thank You.

Comment: Not sure now, but you can cross check this things that may cause this issue. 
Owner of the project should add the email as developer or owner with project access as well, from the share section in project setting. I would suggest better reach to Google Dialogflow support team, in 24 hours they promptly reply resolve this They are much active. All the best